# Unable to Locate Input elements withing a Table in serviceNow - Selenium webriver- java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to input text to a Input field inside a Table in service now. But, the element  is not locatable.

Xpath of the element is :

```
"//*[@id=\"x_f5sl_cl_planning_proposal_table\"]/thead/tr[2]/td[4]/div/div/div/input"
```

Error :

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I tried using action class as well, But did not work.

Is there any other way to locate this  and input values to this field?

Comment: Which Selenium Clients are you using?

Comment: paste your HTML

Comment: I am using Selenium Webriver 2.8.1

Comment: HTML content is : <td data-glide-type="string" data-list_id="x_f5sl_cl_planning_proposal" data-choice="0" name="title" style="" data-type="list2_hdrcell" align="left" class="text-align-left list_hdrcell list_hdr" data-glide-reference-name=""><div class="list_header_search"><div class="list_header_search"><div class="input-group-transparent"><input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="list_header_search  form-control form-control-search" aria-label="Search proposal title"></div></div></div></td>

Comment: Sorry for the dumb Question, There was a iframe. Just switched to the iframe and it worked. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if Your Xpath is correct with eg. Firefox addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/try-xpath/?src=api

Your xpath will be without errers if You write it like this:

```
//*[@id='x_f5sl_cl_planning_proposal_table']/thead/tr[2]/td[4]/div/div/div/input
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb Question, There was a iframe. Just switched to the iframe and it worked. Thanks for your suggestions though.